# Symfony ParamConverter: pass url param to ParamConverter

Tags: php, symfony, converters

I have my Controller with the annotation:

```
/**
* @Rest\Post("/api/questions/question/{question_id}/answer", name="fm.api.post.question.answer")
* @ParamConverter("questionAnswer", options={"id"= "question_id"})
*/
public function postContentAction(QuestionAnswer $questionAnswer, Request $request): Response
    { ...
```

I want to pass the `question_id` param from the url to the param converter. But when I make a dump in my ParamConverter:

```
public function apply(Request $request, ParamConverter $configuration): bool
    {
        dump($configuration);die;
```

I get this:

```
Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\ParamConverter {#3185
  -name: "questionAnswer"
  -class: "App\Model\QuestionAnswer"
  -options: array:1 [
    "id" => "question_id"
  ]
  -isOptional: false
  -converter: null
}
```

So I get the word "`question_id`" instead of teh value in the called url. Can someone say me what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

If you use custom param converter, value of `question_id` is in `Request $request`. You can get it like `$request->get('question_id')`.

Yours apply method can looks like

```
public function apply(Request $request, ParamConverter $configuration): bool
{
    $request->attributes->set($configuration->getName(), new QuestionAnswer($request->get('question_id')));

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Yes that was now my solution, but I want to get the param in the annotations in my controller within the ParamConverter section